# Is it permissible to take a drink during Shemonah Esrei?

Tags: halacha

If someone makes a bracha on a drink before Shemonah Esrei when it is permissible to speak and drink, can he then continue to drink even during Shemonah Esrei at which point he will not have to interrupt Shemonah Esrei to speak? Or is the act of drinking itself during Shemonah Esrei forbidden? Would it make a difference whether he he is doing it for the purpose of improving his davening ie he has a sore throat or whether he is doing it just for pleasure? Would there be a difference whether he is in between brachos or in the middle of a bracha?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I made clear that I'm asking about Shemonah Esrei. Please be more careful about marking duplicates. You should read both questions carefully before making that decision.

Comment: I agree with @Double AA that it's a duplicate. An answer to that question should answer yours as well.

Comment: @MarkA. The other question also asks about Shemonah Esrei.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Actually it doesn't. That question was careful to avoid the issue of Shemonah Esrei. The issue of standing before Hashem during Shemonah Esrei which doesn't apply to the rest of tefillah makes this a totally different question.